# How to show information in the back of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an application that lets the user place an order from the menu. My problem is When the user hovers the mouse over one of the images in the menu, another image should be displayed with the description and price of the item. The id attribute of each image identifies the image to be displayed when it’s rolled over. I tired to manged the first image to flip and show the description and price but the problem is when you click on the first box it does not show the price on the order box and the image is not showing either

```js
$(function(){
  
  //declare prices and varaibles
  var item1 = $("#item1");
  item1.val(7.99);
  
  var item2 = $("#item2");
  item2.val(1.99);
  
  var item3 = $("#item3");
  item3.val(9.99);
  
  var item4 = $("#item4");
  item4.val(12.99);
  
  var item5 = $("#item5");
  item5.val(17.99);
  
  var item6 = $("#item6");
  item6.val(3.99);
 
  var Total = $("#Total");
  var Amount = 0; 
 
  //onclick
  var item = $(".item");
  var txtArea = $("#txtArea");
  var orderList = "";
  
  //Events
  item.click(function(event){
    
    Amount+=parseFloat($(event.target).val());
    orderList+=parseFloat($(event.target).val())+"$ -"+event.target.id  +"\n";
    
    txtArea.val(orderList);
    Total.html("Total: "+Amount.toFixed(2)+"$");
    
   
  });
  
  //Events
  item.hover(function(){
   $(event.target).text($(event.target).val()+"$");
    $(event.target).addClass("dark");
    
  }, function(){
     $(event.target).text("");
    $(event.target).removeClass("dark"); 
});
    
    
  //Clear Button
  var ClearOrder = $("#ClearOrder");
  //Events
  ClearOrder.click(function(){
    
    Amount = 0;
    Total.html("Total: "+Amount.toFixed(2));
    orderList ="";
    txtArea.val(orderList);
  });
    
   
 
            
       
            
 
  
  
  
  
  
  

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: "san-serif";
}

body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  
}

.Outside-Container{
  margin:10px;
  position:absolute;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:5%;
  width:60%;
  height:auto;
  left:20%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
  position:relative;
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
  left:15%;
  overflow:hidden;
 
 
}

.top-logo-holder{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.logo-img{
    width: 31%; 
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.line{
  
  height:2px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  background:teal;
  border-radius:25%;
}

.main-section{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  height:auto;
}

.row1{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row2{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  transition:0.8s;
}

.item{
  width:300px;
  height:17vh;
  background:pink;
  margin:5px;
  color:#fff;
  transition:0.3s;
  font-size:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(1){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/2yCtXwNn/img1.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
 
}

.row1 .item:nth-child(2){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/vTXKRVGk/img2.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
.row1 .item:nth-child(3){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/J7QvH9jx/img3.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}

.row2 .item:nth-child(1){
  background:url("[img4.jpg](https://postimg.cc/hh6pg86y)");
  background-size:cover;
}
.row2 .item:nth-child(2){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
.row2 .item:nth-child(3){
  background:url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}


#txtArea{
  width:60%;
  height:150px;
}

.last-footer-line{
  
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}


.dark{
  filter:brightness(0.7);
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height: 5em;
}


 .flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="js/tabs.js"></script>


<head>
 

<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="Outside-Container">
  <div class = "container">
   
   
   
   
    <div class="top-logo-holder">
     
       <img src ="https://i.postimg.cc/pL36txtW/logo.png" class="logo-img"/>
     
  <div class="line"></div>
     
  </div>  
   
    <div class="main-section">
      <div class ="row1">
        
        <div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <div class="flip"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>Coffee</h1>
      <h1>7.22$</h1>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
         <div class="item" id="item2"></div>
         <div class="item" id="item3"></div>
      </div>
     
       <div class ="row2">
        <div class="item" id="item4"></div>
         <div class="item" id="item5"></div>
         <div class="item" id="item6"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      <p>Your Order:</p>
      <textarea name="message" id="txtArea"></textarea>
       <p id="Total">Total: </p>
    </div>  
   
   
    <div class="last-footer-line">
      <button id="PlaceOrder">Place Order</button>
       <button id="ClearOrder">Clear Order</button>
      <div>
     
     
    </div>
   
   
   
   
</div>
</div>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tabs.js"></script>
</body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: z-index determines the order of showing.

Comment: Your problem is using `filter` on class `.item`. The entire content will go darker on hover. Lose the filter. In the mean time: answer pending...

Comment: @Grumpy thank you for replying back .it does not work
https://codepen.io/farahi1817/pen/zYGavEa

Comment: @RenevanderLende thank you for replaying back if look at the first image i manged to flip the first image but when i click in the first image it does not show me the price 
https://codepen.io/farahi1817/pen/zYGavEa

Comment: You will need to restructure your html and modify your JS to react on a `.flip-card` click. At the moment it gets triggered by an `.item` click. Also create something like `.flip-card .item .price` so you can access the price of the item clicked in JS

Comment: @RenevanderLende i really did not get can you explain it a bit more honestly im really lost now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**
OP modified question to reflect actual requirements.

New answer:

- all your `.item`s need to look like the first `.flip-card`.
- you are combing some previous try (items) with a new try (flipcard) but forgot to properly adjust the CSS and the JS to reflect the changes. I changes the `item` eventlistener to work with `flipcard` and `flipcard` ONLY.
- modified second `<h1>` in the flipcard, `<h1 id="item1">`
- Modified the calculations in the `flipcard.onclick` to show the amounts

The code of this answer is from your [codepen](https://codepen.io/farahi1817/pen/zYGavEa) modified with my changes.

**UPDATE 2**

- Major HTML change: turned all items into flipcards. One of the problems was that you assigned `value`s to elements that cannot have `value`s. jQuery `val()` function only operates on elements that can have `value`s like `<input>`
- removed all references to `item` from CSS

**UPDATE 3**

Fixed NaN problem, flipcard child elements needed to ignore click event (CSS), as JS got the wrong element reference. CSS and JS corrected. Also added `.price` in HTML for JS to easily find the price tag.

Leaving finetuning and this 'n thats to you...

```js
$(function() {
//declare prices and varaibles
var item1 = $("#item1");
item1.val(7.99);

var item2 = $("#item2");
item2.val(1.99);

var item3 = $("#item3");
item3.val(9.99);

var item4 = $("#item4");
item4.val(12.99);

var item5 = $("#item5");
item5.val(17.99);

var item6 = $("#item6");
item6.val(3.99);

var Total = $("#Total");
var Amount = 0;

var txtArea = $("#txtArea");
var orderList = "";

// onclick, CHANGED
// Events, CHANGED
$(".flip-card").click(function(event) {

var priceTag = $(event.target).find('.price');
var price    = Number(priceTag.val());

  Amount += price;
  orderList += price + "$ - " + priceTag[0].id + "\n";

  txtArea.text(orderList);
  
  // Only round the final value
  Total.html("Total: " + Amount.toFixed(2) + "$");
});

//Clear Button
var ClearOrder = $("#ClearOrder");
//Events
ClearOrder.click(function() {
  Amount = 0;
  Total.html("Total: " + Amount.toFixed(2));
  orderList = "";
  txtArea.val(orderList);
});
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "san-serif";
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.Outside-Container {
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  left: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  left: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-logo-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.logo-img {
  width: 31%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: teal;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

.main-section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

/* MODIFIED */
/* IDs starting with 'flip' */
[id^="flip"] { background-size: cover }

/* flipcard front images */
#flip1 { background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/2yCtXwNn/img1.jpg") }
#flip2 { background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/vTXKRVGk/img2.jpg") }
#flip3 { background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/J7QvH9jx/img3.jpg") }
#flip4 { background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/hh6pg86y/img4.jpg") }
#flip5 { background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg") }
#flip6 { background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/vZ4NjTk2/img5.jpg") }
/**/

/* ADDED */
.flip-card * {
/*
    needed for jQuery onclick,
    flipcard children (h1,#item,etc) must ignore clicksss.
*/
 pointer-events: none;
}

[id^="item"] {
 width: 300px;
 border: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: currentColor;
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center
}

#txtArea {
  width: 60%;
  height: 150px;
}

.last-footer-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* OBSOLETE
.dark {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 5em;
}
*/

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* little debug helper */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed Crimson }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body outlines="0">
    <div class="Outside-Container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top-logo-holder">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/pL36txtW/logo.png" class="logo-img" />
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="main-section">
                <div class="row1">
                    <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div id="flip1" class="flip-card-front">
                                <div class="flip"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>Espresso</h1>
                                <input class="price" id="item1" type="text" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div id="flip2" class="flip-card-front">
                                <div class="flip"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>Chocolat Milk</h1>
                                <input class="price" id="item2" type="text" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div id="flip3" class="flip-card-front">
                                <div class="flip"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>Cappuchino</h1>
                                <input class="price" id="item3" type="text" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row2">
                    <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div id="flip4" class="flip-card-front">
                                <div class="flip"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>Coffee</h1>
                                <input class="price" id="item4" type="text" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div id="flip5" class="flip-card-front">
                                <div class="flip"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>Cookie 1</h1>
                                <input class="price" id="item5" type="text" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flip-card">
                        <div class="flip-card-inner">
                            <div id="flip6" class="flip-card-front">
                                <div class="flip"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>Cookie 2</h1>
                                <input class="price" id="item6" type="text" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="line"></div>
                <p>Your Order:</p>
                <textarea name="message" id="txtArea"></textarea>
                <p id="Total">Total:</p>
            </div>

            <div class="last-footer-line">
                <button id="PlaceOrder">Place Order</button>
                <button id="ClearOrder">Clear Order</button>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me i really appreciated your help but this is not what i wanted .
if look at the following link , if u check the first image when u move hover it it flip and show the price but my problem is when i click on the image it does not show me the price https://codepen.io/farahi1817/pen/zYGavEa

Comment: @marie, then the text in your question does not reflect what you need. The Pen clears that up a bit, but it still is not clear "WHAT price of WHICH image should be displayed WHERE" and if this should be placed in the 'your order' box. Please take some time to rephrase your question and be more specific then I can change my answer accordingly...

Comment: @marie Don't worry about the language, its fine. But the code you posted in your question differs from the code in the pen, you will understand that will add to the confusion as we have to work with what you give us. You better rethink what your problem is and edit the question to make sure we get ALL the information needed to help you get going again. (going to have dinner, need to wait...)

Comment: Van de lende sorry for my bad English i will do my best to explain it again .So if you open the code pen u see 6 boxes with 6 different images when u put ur mouse hover on one of them the it should flip like the first box (the blue box and it suppose to be an image instead of the blue box ).so my problem is when i click on the blue box it should show me the price on the order box but it does not show the price on the order box

Comment: please let me know if it does not make sense i will try to explain again

Comment: i asked my friend to explain it better i hope it does not bring confusing .
when the user hovers the mouse over one of the images in the menu another image should be displayed with the description and price of the item. The id attribute of each image identifies the image to be displayed when it's rolled over

Comment: @marie, pls stop posting comments, but modify your question. This is not me nagging, but 1) now other people need to read all the comments to understand what your want/need (which they won't). 2) in future, when people want to add new things or answers, they too need to read all the comments. 3) Rewriting your question will (hopefully) force you to rethink what you want and maybe you will find what you did wrong yourself...Plus, most importantly make sure the code you posted is equal to the code in the pen.

Comment: i rewrite my question