# Responsive photo gallery, with image flip on click revealing descriptive text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to do this fun photo album/gallery for my family as my first project, I have almost everything working the way I want; the layout is responsive, each photo can flip individually... However I am stuck trying to add a back to the photo displaying some text (date taken/small description).

Here is the code I have written so far, any feedback is appreciated:

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
  ready()
}

const fileInput = document.querySelector("#fileInput");
var uploaded_image = "";

fileInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    uploaded_image = reader.result;
    document.querySelector("#displayImage").src = reader.result
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
})


const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

});

function flip(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("flipped");
}


photo.addEventListener('click', flipPhoto);

photo.addEventListener('touchstart', flipPhoto);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Poppins;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/NcDdW2X.jpg);
}

.album-photos {
  display: grid;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 50px 0 50px;
}

.main-header {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
}

.header-text {
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #f7f7f7, 0 0 5px #ffffff;
  color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.9);
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.container .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: auto
}

.album {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 32.5%;
}

.container .box .album img,
.container .box .album video {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #56ccf2;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.67em;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.btn-upload:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-upload {
  display: center;
}

\#displayImage {
  display: flex;
  width: 375px;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container .box {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container .box .album {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/\* image flip on click \*/ .flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-header">
    <h1 class="gallary-title">Family <span class="header-text">Photos</span> Album</h1>
    <nav class="main-nav"></nav>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="album">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic2.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic3.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic4.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic5.jgp" onclick="flip(this)">
        <video class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/video.mp4" controls onclick="flip(this)"></video>
      </div>
      <div class="album">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">

      </div>
      <div class="album">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
        <video class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/video2.mp4" controls onclick="flip(this)"></video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <form action="/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="files[]" multiple style="display: none;">
        <button class="btn btn-upload" type="button " onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();">Upload</button>
        <img id="displayImage">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your Javascript code as well?

Comment: Just added the JavaScript! Thanks for catching that pal~

Comment: I've converted your code into a Snippet, which can demonstrate your code in the question (and are also available in answers); unfortunately `ready()` is not defined; can you check the code to make sure it works here as it does in your own code, and edit it if not? Also, while we appreciate the code being posted we do ask that you post only the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code, not *all* of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your code a bit, and I'll explain along the way.

First, I've stripped your code of everything not related to the image Y-axis flipping issue, just to make things more focused. That includes removing the title, the videos, and some of the images.

Next, in order to have real images to work with, I've used placeholder.com's images of various resolution. Everything up until (and including) this step was done for simplification.

First significant change to your code was done in the way the elements are organized. Specifically, this part:

```
  <div class="album">
    <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic1.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
    <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic2.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
    <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic3.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
    <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic4.jpg" onclick="flip(this)">
    <img class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/pic5.jgp" onclick="flip(this)">
    <video class="album-photos" src="Images/Photos/video.mp4" controls onclick="flip(this)"></video>
  </div>
```

was remade into this:

```
      <div class="album">
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x650">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Lorem ipsum<br>2022-12-20</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        .....
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Sit dolor amet<br>2021-11-10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

This was done in order to keep the current CSS without introducing any major changes (imgContainer and imgHolder fill that role), and to enable us to cheat (somewhat) by introducing a false back to our images - that's what `div.infoHolder` is for. That false back also contains image information - when was the image taken, a short description, etc.

Also, the `onclick` event was moved to the immediate parent of the `img.album-photos`. The reasoning behind this was to have it act like a switch:

- on page load, the image information is hidden
- once we click the `div.imageHolder`, the image is flipped, and the information contained inside `div.infoHolder` is also flipped, and *revealed*
- if we click on it again, the image flips back, but so does the `div.infoHolder`, going back to it's original (page load) Y position, and it also reverts to its hidden state

The CSS part holds some new things to make it all work. Specifically, these:

- `.imgContainer` follows the same rules as `.container .box .album img`
- `.flipped` no longer has a `background` CSS property, for simplicity
- `.album-photos` class has two new CSS properties, for a smooth flip-back
- `.infoHolder` is absolutely positioned, and has its `rotateY` set both inherently, and when combined with the `.flipped` class. `backface-visbility` is the key thing here

Lastly, the JS changes. Since our `div.infoHolder` keeps all the information we want to show when the image is flipped along its Y axis, we need to toggle its `.flipped` class at the same time we do that for the `.album-photos` image.

Please note that the example is not quite perfect, but it should give you an idea what to do.

For a more elaborate example (which includes flipping when hovering over an image), please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60726699/).

```js
function flip(element) {
  var image = element.querySelector("img.album-photos");
  var infoHolder = element.querySelector("div.infoHolder");

  infoHolder.classList.toggle("flipped");
  image.classList.toggle("flipped");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Poppins;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/NcDdW2X.jpg);
}

.album-photos {
  display: grid;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 50px 0 50px;
}

.main-header {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.container .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: auto;
}

.album {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 32.5%;
}

.container .box .album img,
.container .box .album video,
.imgContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container .box {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container .box .album {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* image flip on click */
.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.imgHolder {
  position: relative;
}

.infoHolder {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  color: white;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.infoHolder.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x650">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Lorem ipsum<br>2022-12-20</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Sit dolor amet<br>2021-11-10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x250">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Aliquam sed nulla sed lectus lobortis dapibus<br>2020-07-25</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x250">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Duis et leo velit. Nulla facilisi.<br>2022-01-09</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="album">
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x650">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Mauris egestas lectus quis metus<br>2022-07-20</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x650">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Duis posuere, quam eget iaculis gravida<br>2022-07-19</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x650">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis<br>2022-07-18</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="album">
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x650">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Suspendisse sed ante nec sem<br>2022-08-20</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imgContainer">
          <div class="imgHolder" onclick="flip(this)">
            <img class="album-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x650">
            <div class="infoHolder flipped">Aliquam sit amet eleifend sapien<br>2022-08-15</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```